# How to incorporate mimalloc into a cmake project?

Tags: c++, cmake, dll, linker, mimalloc

I'm trying to implement mimalloc (https://github.com/microsoft/mimalloc) into my project by following this guide (https://github.com/microsoft/mimalloc#override_on_windows) to override the default malloc but I can't get the mimalloc-override.dll to generate.

My CMake is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project(OpenGLPlayground2)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(SRC_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")
set(RES_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/res")
set(LIB_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")

add_executable(OpenGLPlayground2 src/main.cpp)

set(MIMALLOC_DIR "${LIB_DIR}/mimalloc-master")
set(MI_OVERRIDE ON CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
set(MI_USE_CXX ON CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
set(MI_WIN_REDIRECT ON CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
set(MI_BUILD_SHARED ON CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
add_subdirectory(${MIMALLOC_DIR})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} mimalloc)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "${MIMALLOC_DIR}/include")
```

But the cmake output is

```
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- 
-- Override standard malloc (MI_OVERRIDE=ON)
-- Use the C++ compiler to compile (MI_USE_CXX=ON)
-- 
-- Library base name: mimalloc
-- Version          : 2.0
-- Build type       : release
-- C++ Compiler     : C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe
-- Compiler flags   : /Zc:__cplusplus
-- Compiler defines : 
-- Link libraries   : psapi;shell32;user32;advapi32;bcrypt
-- Build targets    : shared;static;object;tests
-- 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/charl/CLionProjects/OpenGLPlayground2/cmake-build-release
```

Seemingly ignoring the options, I set. But even then it looks like it should create the mimalloc-override.dll.

Here is a picture of the files produced by [mimalloc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7VnZ.png). In case the image doesn't load it shows mimalloc.dll/lib and mimalloc-redirect32.dll

My main.cpp file is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mimalloc.h"

int main()
{
    mi_version();
    std::cout << "hi\n";
}
```

And that outputs the error:

```
C:\Users\charl\CLionProjects\OpenGLPlayground2\cmake-build-release\OpenGLPlayground2.exe

Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)
```

Thanks for any help I receive.